# Python request convert string to JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm using the requests library in Python to do a post request, but I'm having a problem when I read a value from a spreadsheet.

The following code works (returns a 201 status code):

```
url = 'http://myport:8092//api/Accounts/1000/Users'
item = {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith", "userName": "JSmith"}
r = requests.post(url, json = item)
print(r.status_code)
```

As soon as I read "item" from a cell in a spreadsheet, a 501 error code gets returned. When I print out "item" after reading it from the spreadsheet, the output matches the value for item shown above.

I haven't been able to find a solution, the only thing I can think of is that the problem is that it's being read as a string?

Do I need to convert it into a json object before I run the post?

Comment: You're going to need to show the full code you're actually using. How are you "reading item from a call in a spreadsheet"? What *exactly* is the value that you then pass to requests?

Comment: item = self.ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value, it returns exactly what I printed above for item.

Answer (score 1):

501 is the error code for `not implemented`. It looks like the url you're sending to doesn't accept post requests. Is the url correct?

Comment: Yes, the url works. It only fails when I read "item" from a spreadsheet instead of assigning it directly as I did above.

Comment: @Chris where did the spreadsheet come from? How do you access a spreadsheet?

Comment: I use the spreadsheet to store my data. I use openpyxl to read the data:    item = self.ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value

Comment: @Chris that's a different question then